# Detecting Proximity of Paired Bluetooth LE devices (i.e. iPhone, Apple Watch) from Mac

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

From macOS, I'd like to detect the presence/proximity of already paired (via iCloud) Bluetooth LE devices such as a user's iPhone or Apple Watch. Is there a way to do this without running a custom-built app on the user's iPhone/Watch?

I can easily get a list of devices using CoreBluetooth, and seemingly also get RSSI signal strength from this device list, but I don't see a way to correlate the random UUID  with a known device, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53068911/cbperipheral-and-apple-watch).

I've looked at some possible solutions including turning an iPhone into an iBeacon and the [MultipeerConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity?language=objc) framework, but it looks like both of these require an app to be running on all devices (Mac, iPhone, and Watch). An example app that does not appear to require an app running on the iPhone/Watch is [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/smart-insomnia/id1447041581?mt=12).

Please note that I am working within a sandboxed environment. Thank you in advance for any suggestions.